# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix when using android:id or android:text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I just started writing java/android and I cant for the life of me figure out why I am getting the `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix` error and the `attribute is missing the android namespace prefix.` I am using Eclipse. The **`Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`** error is from the line:

```
andriod:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
```

and the **`attribute is missing the android namespace prefix`** is from:

```
andriod:text="Add One"
andriod:layout_gravity="center"
andriod:textSize="20dp"
```

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.Marett.Driod.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Total"
        android:textSize="45sp" 
        andriod:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    andriod:text="Add One"
    andriod:layout_gravity="center"
    andriod:textSize="20dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you maybe meant to write android instead of andriod?

Answer (score 1):

andriod -> android 
That's why it can't find prefix

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in **andrIOd**. Change:

```
andriod:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
```

Do the same at all lines where that kind of typo is.